# What are tensorflow summaries? How exactly are they utilized when using a tf model to make predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Posting here as I couldn't find an explicit answer from tensorflow's documentation. I am curious about the actual purpose of the summary files in tensorflow. After training, I call the tensor flow model (the model file and the meta file) that were saved by:

```
tf.train.saver()
```

There seems to be no need for me to actually keep the summary files apart from logging training information;I can use my models to predict without referencing the summaries.
Is the summary file merely just log files of the training runs (accuracy and loss). Is there any other purpose that these files serve?

Comment: You don't need summaries to make predictions, they are there to monitor training through tensorboard

Comment: Thanks! The purpose of keeping them makes more sense now.